# Styling alertDialogBuilder buttons

Tags: java, android, user-interface, dialog, styles

I want to add custom style to negative and positive buttons I use in `alertDialogBuilder`. How can this be done? Is it somehow possible to create styles with XML and use it in all `alertDialogBuilder` buttons? In my case I want all the texts in `alertdialog` buttons to have dotted underlines.

I have tried to figure how to set colors for buttons but this is not enough.

```
...
alertDialog.show(); alertDialog.getButton(alertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

The expected results would be to be able to define style that can be easily used in all `alertDialogBuilder` buttons.

Comment: go thorugh this link, https://github.com/Hemen07/Nimbus-Todo-pad-Reminder/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/location_picker.xml, https://github.com/Hemen07/Nimbus-Todo-pad-Reminder/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/redfox/nimbustodo/weather/weather_util/UtilLocationDialog.java,  https://github.com/Hemen07/Nimbus-Todo-pad-Reminder/blob/master/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml, put your own color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, U can create a style in ur styles.xml file and call this style/theme as wherever u want. U can try with below code

```
<style name="MyCustomThemeForAlertDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>

    <!-- U can call another style as your desired style-->
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/MyMsgBodyTextAppearance</item>
</style>
<style name="MyMsgBodyTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Medium">
    <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
    <item name="android:left">-5dp</item>
    <item name="android:right">-5dp</item>
    <item name="android:top">-5dp</item>
    <item name="android:dashWidth">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:dashGap">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:width">1dp</item>
</style>
```

Then call your created theme in code as below

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.MyCustomThemeForAlertDialog);
builder.setCancelable(false);
builder.setTitle("Title");
builder.setMessage("Do you want to Quit?");
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this guide to apply style in your alertdialog. 
    [How to style AlertDialogs like a pro](http://blog.supenta.com/2014/07/02/how-to-style-alertdialogs-like-a-pro/)